# show other months in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to show other months as '-' in my jquery ui datepicker.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true
});
```

The above code shows the other month dates. But, I need to show other months date as '-'.

For Ex,

[image]

Kindly Anyone help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find anything that allows you to control the text that is displayed in the "other month" cells but you can kludge your way around it.

Guganeshan.T is on the right track. But the tricky part is applying the change at the right time. The `beforeShow` and `onChangeMonthYear` events are fired *before* the new month is displayed and there are *after* versions of those events. My usual trick for situations like this is to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a timeout of zero, that effectively lets you queue up a function to be called once the browser gets control again and that's after the current chunk of JavaScript has finished running. So something like this should do the trick:

```
function ickyHyphenKludge(inst) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        inst.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-other-month span.ui-state-default').html('-');
    }, 0);
}

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: false,
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        ickyHyphenKludge(inst);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        ickyHyphenKludge(inst);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YKNmV/1/

That's pretty kludgey and smelly but it works, it should be pretty solid, and I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the CSS used in the jQuery UI's DatePicker control. They use the class `ui-priority-secondary` for dates in other months.

So what you can do is, use jQuery to locate elements that use that particular class and replace the HTML to `-` and center it.

I tried the following and it worked.

`$('.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-priority-secondary').html('-').css('text-align', 'center')`

Hope that helps

**UPDATE:**

Since I checked it only with the `Firebug` console, didn't see the scenario where it won't be applied at the right time. [@mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) has pointed that out and has a working solution.

Comment: The problem is applying that at the right time, the HTML in the datepicker is rebuilt every time the month changes (including the initial display) so some trickery is needed to get the hyphens in *after* jQuery-UI is done with the HTML. But +1 for being on the right track.

Comment: Good catch! I used the firebug console to check it. Since it was applied on the already-rendered calendar, I got carried away ;) thx